# SQL Procedure tp run another procedure with multiple inputs

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to run a procedure **exec remove_job_procedure 'job_id'** which takes a job_id, which removes the job from list. Now I have a Select Job_id query which return multiple jobs of certain types. Can I write another procedure which will run the remove_job_procedure multiple the times we have job ids from select job_id query?

First Query:

- select job_id where job_type in 'job_type_1' - This results 1q2w3e, 2w3e1q, 2w3e4r - these three ids.

2nd Query:

- exec remove_job_procedure '1q2w3e'
- exec remove_job_procedure '2w3e1q'
- exec remove_job_procedure '2w3e4r'

I need to create a new procedure which will feed job id from first query into 2nd query(procedure) one by one.

Thanks

Comment: Seems like a product specific question. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: SQL server 2012

Comment: There are several options. I would select the list into a local table, open a cursor on that local table and loop removing the jobs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you have a lot of JOB_ID CURSOR may not be a good idea to use it will be to long to execute cause it will execute row by row but for a bulk treatement if you have more then 10000 ID and for better  performance use this : 'there is also a lot of ways to excute the proc '

```
DECLARE @PractitionerId varchar(50) , @count int , @first_insert int
declare @table  table  (id_job varchar(50))   
declare @table2 table  (id varchar(50))

insert into @table 
select '1q2w3e' union
select '2w3e1q'  union
select '2w3e4r' union 
select 'toto'


/* You statement will start from here cause  you already have the result id the job_id */

insert into @table2
select concat('remove_job_procedure',job_id) from job where job_type in 'job_type_1'

set @first_insert = 1
set @count = (select count(*) from @table2)

while @first_insert <= @count
BEGIN
        set @PractitionerId = (select id from 
                            (select row_number() over(order by id ) as rowcounts , id from @table2)  d
                         where d.rowcounts = @first_insert)

        --select @PractitionerId 

        exec @PractitionerId

    set @first_insert = @first_insert+1
END
```

Answer (score 0):

-

Here is what you need the first declare i did juste to get the date into my table you already have the result use select statement to insert into table

```
declare @table table (id_job varchar(50))
Declare @next_id_JOb varchar(50) , @procedure varchar(max)
insert into @table 
/* here use the select statement to return the liste od the id's that you have 
        i used this do get the result */
select '1q2w3e' union
select '2w3e1q' union
select '2w3e4r'


DECLARE job CURSOR 
FOR  SELECT  id_job FROM @table
OPEN job

FETCH NEXT FROM job INTO @next_id_JOb

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN  


            set @procedure = concat('remove_job_procedure',@next_id_JOb)

            Exec @procedure

      -- select @procedure

        FETCH NEXT FROM job INTO @next_id_JOb
    END -- END BOUCLE WHILE
CLOSE job
DEALLOCATE job
```

Result of the test i did select to select the name cause i don't have the store procedures

[Results od the liste that will be executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GelRo.png)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was able to understand just by going thru line by line. Most likely this would solve my problem.